# Save trained gensim word2vec model as a tensorflow SavedModel

Tags: tensorflow, gensim, word2vec

Do we have an option to save a trained Gensim Word2Vec model as a saved model using tf 2.0 `tf.saved_model.save`? In other words, how can I save a trained embedding vector as a saved model signature to work with tensorflow 2.0. The following steps are not correct normally:

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(...)

model.init_sims(..)

model.train(..)

model.save(..)

module = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec(...)

tf.saved_model.save(
    module, 
    export_dir
)
```

EDIT:

This example helped me about how to do it : https://keras.io/examples/nlp/pretrained_word_embeddings/

Comment: Gensim's `KeyedVectors` doesn't use Tensorflow in any way, so you probably want to use its own native `.save()`. Also, a `Word2Vec` model that's saved with `.save()` would be loaded with `Word2Vec.load(...)`. (I'm not sure what you're doing withe the `KeyedVector.load_word2vec_format()` method, but that method can't do anything with what you've saved earlier. And without showing the error message/stack you've received, it's not clear what you might mean by "do not work".)

Answer (score 0):

Gensim does not use TensorFlow and it has [its own methods](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.save) for loading and saving models.

You would need to convert Gensim embeddings into a TensorFlow a model which only makes sense if you further plan to use your embeddings within TensorFlow and possibly fine-tune them for your task.

Gensim Word2Vec are two steps in TensorFlow:

1. [Vocabulary lookup](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lookup/StaticVocabularyTable): a table that assigns indices to tokens.
2. [Embedding lookup layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding) that picks up the actual embeddings for the indices.

Then, you can save it as any other TensorFlow model.